# redis fails to get CONFIG when using redis-benchmark

Tags: ssl, redis, tls1.2

I have redis 7 server setup to provide only secure TLS connection and verified it is working properly using redis-cli.
But when I do redis-benchmark, I get this error:

```
ERROR: failed to fetch CONFIG from 127.0.0.1:6379
WARNING: Could not fetch server CONFIG
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Have you renamed `CONFIG` command? Are you able to run the benchmark without TLS enabled?

Comment: I have not renamed CONFIG command. I have not tested running without TLS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command is working OK for me over an only TLS Redis Server.

```
./src/redis-benchmark --tls --cert ./tests/tls/redis.crt --key ./tests/tls/redis.key --cacert ./tests/tls/ca.crt

====== PING_INLINE ======
  100000 requests completed in 1.76 seconds
  50 parallel clients
...
```

Redis server has been started using

```
./src/redis-server --tls-port 6379 --port 0 --tls-cert-file ./tests/tls/redis.crt --tls-key-file ./tests/tls/redis.key --tls-ca-cert-file ./tests/tls/ca.crt
```

Keys and certs have been generated using [Redis TLS documentation](https://redis.io/docs/manual/security/encryption/)

You can check all `redis-benchmark` tls related options

```
./src/redis-benchmark --help
Usage: redis-benchmark [OPTIONS] [COMMAND ARGS...]

Options:
 --tls              Establish a secure TLS connection.
 --cacert <file>    CA Certificate file to verify with.
 --cacertdir <dir>  Directory where trusted CA certificates are stored.
                    If neither cacert nor cacertdir are specified, the default
                    system-wide trusted root certs configuration will apply.
 --insecure         Allow insecure TLS connection by skipping cert validation.
 --cert <file>      Client certificate to authenticate with.
 --key <file>       Private key file to authenticate with.
 --tls-ciphers <list> Sets the list of preferred ciphers (TLSv1.2 and below)
                    in order of preference from highest to lowest separated by colon (":").
                    See the ciphers(1ssl) manpage for more information about the syntax of this string.
 --tls-ciphersuites <list> Sets the list of preferred ciphersuites (TLSv1.3)
                    in order of preference from highest to lowest separated by colon (":").
                    See the ciphers(1ssl) manpage for more information about the syntax of this string,
                    and specifically for TLSv1.3 ciphersuites.
```

non-tls related options have been omitted.